# geom bar for multiplay variables (columns) in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data set with multiplay variables which referes to sympthoms people have (0 exist,1 is not exist)

I would like to put all of them in geom bar on x axis, and the y axis will be the count of them in my dataset.

[image]

```
 ggplot(tested_individuals, aes(x=Cough)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput` instead of sharing images?

Comment: Pivot your data so that you have one column for question and one column for response for each participant and your life will become much easier.  In this format, your data frame is tidy.  `ggplot` *likes* tidy data.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~Cough, ~Fever, ~Head_ache,
  0, 1, 1,
  0, 1, 0,
  1, 1, 1
)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

This assumes that all columns are to be plotted.
Insert `select(Cough, Fever)` before `pivot_longer` to only plot those two properties.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to point out is that not all of your variables are numeric, so for consistency you should replace the `Age_60_or_over` and `Corona_result` columns with 1s and 0s too. The `Test_indication` column does not have a binary outcome so cannot be included as a bar.

The next thing to do is to reshape your data into a table format.

We can take your initial data and perform these two steps like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_table <- df %>%
  mutate(Age_60_and_above = if_else(Age_60_and_above == "Yes", 1, 0),
         Corona_positive = if_else(Corona_result == "Positive", 1, 0)) %>%
  select(-Test_indication, -Corona_result) %>%
  colSums() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames("Count") %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "Feature") 

my_table
#>               Feature Count
#> 1               Cough     2
#> 2               Fever     2
#> 3         Sore_throat     1
#> 4 Shortness_of_breath     0
#> 5           Head_ache     1
#> 6    Age_60_and_above     1
#> 7     Corona_positive    14
```

Now we can plot this table as a bar graph using `ggplot`

```
ggplot(my_table, aes(Feature, Count, fill = Feature)) +
  geom_col(fill = "deepskyblue4") +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Data used - transcribed from image in question**

```r
df <- structure(list(Cough = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), Fever = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Sore_throat = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Shortness_of_breath = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Head_ache = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Corona_result = c("Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", "Positive", 
"Positive"), Age_60_and_above = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), 
Test_indication = c("Other", 
"Other", "Other", "Other", "Abroad", "Abroad", "Other", "Other", 
"Contact with confirmed", "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other", 
"Other")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```